# What is the name for this hash table optimization?

Tags: algorithm, hashtable, addressing

While implementing a custom hash table with open addressing, I discovered that for my application, it helps performance if I swap the probed element in a row of filled slots with the one in the first probe location. (To optimize the table to quicker yield often-accessed elements)

Is there a name for this optimization?

Comment: In general this approach is called MRU caching. It's not specific to hash tables though.

Comment: Thanks. I googled 'caching' and 'move to front' but only found articles about hash tables being used for implementing caches... I am wondering whether there are more variants for optimizing read accesses and what they (and this) are called in the literature, to -if available- try them out in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is very similar to the [*list update* problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_update_problem#Deterministic) from the field of [online-competitive algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm).

The solution you used is known as [MTF (move to front)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_update_problem#Deterministic). This solution is known to be 2-competitive, meaning that it will do at most twice as bad as a hypothetical adversary which knows the future in advance.

Note that you can do slightly better than that with the [bit algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_update_problem#Randomized), which requires another bit + random op, but is 7-4 competitive.

Comment: Thank you, **list update problem** indeed seems to be appropriate! I looked for _hash table_ related links, but should have figured that a run of filled probing locations can of course be seen as a _list_ ...

Comment: You're welcome. FWIW, I think it's a fascinating problem too. Note that if you would have used collision chaining, it would have been exactly this problem. Probing is slightly different - the cost of moving the last item to some position, shifting everything back, is not constant as in a list. Nevertheless, I think this is the closest problem to yours.

Answer (score 1):

The most general term for this kind of optimization is probably [self-organization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-organising_heuristic).

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed a good term. I found an old paper apparently describing the swapping: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020019085901036 
I didn't buy the paper yet - but the first page is shown, and my optimization appears to be called method H2 in there.